# Two column unique constraint ActiveAndroid

Tags: activeandroid

How can I add two column unique constraint in ActiveAndroid?
I tried to add 2.sql and increase DB version, but it doesnt seem to be updated correctly (probably because I reinstall the app?). Anyway, is there are way to add some annotation on which I can apply two column unique constraint in ActiveAndroid ?

```
<meta-data android:name="AA_DB_NAME" android:value="Diggecard.db" />
<meta-data android:name="AA_DB_VERSION" android:value="2" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the uniqueGroups property in the @Column annotation.

Make sure both columns have the same group name and they both must define the constraint.

```
@Column(uniqueGroups = {"groupName"}, onUniqueConflicts = {ConflictAction.FAIL})

@Column(uniqueGroups = {"groupName"}, onUniqueConflicts = {ConflictAction.FAIL})
```

There is actually a sample included [here](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/blob/master/src/com/activeandroid/annotation/Column.java#L51-L69), in the source.

Comment: Thanks! Will test it out!