# activeandroid: multiple columns as unqiue together in a table

Tags: unique, multiple-columns, activeandroid

I am trying to make 2 columns as unique together in activeandroid using the solution provided in the link: [Two column unique constraint ActiveAndroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868563/two-column-unique-constraint-activeandroid) but its just not working. Compiler is unable to find the "uniqueGroups" and "ConflictAction". I have imported Column class as well but still not working.

I am currently using activeandroid version 3.0, Looking forward to some solution. Code snippet is given below for reference

```
@Table(name = "Farmer")
public class Farmer extends Model {

    @Column(name = "image_path")
    public String image_path;

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "online_id")
    public int online_id;

    @Expose
    @Column(name = "name", uniqueGroups={"group1"}, onUniqueConflicts={ConflictAction.FAIL})
    public String name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a dependency issue. Check for the appropriate "compile ..." statement that you need to add to the build.gradle file for your app. For ActiveAndroid 3.1.0 you may need:     compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'

Also, having dependencies added to the project using gradle compile statements like the one above AND jar file dependencies may cause conflicts. Choose one of the two methods to avoid that.